# Apple concern over customized UIAlertView in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I have used UIAlertview in the iPhone application that is customized a little bit.I have added three  buttons in the UIAlertview and some text in between two buttons.

Please let me know if apple have any concerns if UIALertView is customized with text in between two buttons.

UIAlerView screen is as described below,

```
                     Title Alert Message
                        First Button 
                        Second Button
                        (Text message)
                        Cancel Button
```

I cant attach image here as i need to get more than 10 reputation points here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I've had no issues with modifying UIAlertViews in any way.  I don't think Apple will care.